# How to manage modules best approach in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I wanted to make my future projects very modular, In all the projects I heavily rely on Firebase, Ads, RoomDatabase.

So I started modularizing the boilerplate code of all these into separate modules, one of the main module is baseProject which handles interfacing between all these modules, my main issue is every time I sync the project with a single change in gradle it takes 15-20 minutes (Running in Macbook pro 13 inch 2017 model) Whereas projects without these modules build quite faster.

here are the `settings.gradle` which links all the external modules to a new project looks like :

[image]

And this is how the baseproject linked to new project in app.gradle file :

[image]

and finally this is how a typical module structure looks like :

[image]

Also for more info on how the above module is handling the firebase libraries this is how the Gradle for firebase module looks like.

[image]

### PROBLEM

I just need to reduce the sync time while building gradle, it's taking too much time and I believe it's synching all the dependencies in each module every time as fresh,I just need to make it sync everything once and make sure next time the build time is reduced to few minutes which is acceptable.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Enable offline mode:** If you are on a slow network connection, your build times may suffer when Gradle attempts to use network resources to resolve dependencies. You can tell Gradle to avoid using network resources by using only the artifacts that it has cached locally.

**To use Gradle offline when building with Android Studio, proceed as follows ->**

1. Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).
2. In the left pane, click Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.
3. Check the Offline work checkbox.
4. Click Apply or OK.

Comment: Hi, I did that earlier but it messes up with my other projects where Android studio gives warning and option to disable offline mode, I was wondering if there is some other way where we can disable syncing of modules and only sync the main project, the way it works when you have .aar or .jar libraries, which I have noticed works much faster in building.